# Using code generation (like Scala Meta) to scrape boilerplate

Tags: scala, macros, code-generation, scalameta

I use Shapeless's tagged types to get nice typesafe primitives to pass through my business logic. Defining these types started with a simple:

```
sealed trait MyTaggedStringTag
type MyTaggedString = String @@ MyTaggedStringTag
```

But I've added a good bit of helper logic to this, and now my definitions look more like:

```
sealed trait MyTaggedStringTag

type MyTaggedString = String @@ MyTaggedStringTag
object MyTaggedString {
  def fromString(untaggedMyTaggedString: String): MyTaggedString = {
    val myTaggedString = tag[MyTaggedStringTag](untaggedMyTaggedString)
    myTaggedString
  }
}
implicit class MyTaggedStringOps(val myTaggedString: MyTaggedString) extends AnyVal { def untagged = myTaggedString.asInstanceOf[String] }
```

So, it's a lot of boilerplate per definition. I'd really like to be able to generate this by doing something like:

```
@tagged[String] type MyTaggedString
```

Is there a way to do something like this with Scala Meta, or some other code generation tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

This is now fully working and can be seen in a new library I call [Taggy](https://github.com/acjay/taggy). Here is the latest version of the macro:

```
class tagged extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    // Macro annotation type and value parameters come back as AST data, not 
    // values, and are accessed by destructuring `this`.
    defn match {
      case q"..$mods type $newType = ${underlyingType: Type.Name}" => 
        TaggedImpl.expand(underlyingType, newType, mods)
      case _ => 
        abort("Correct usage: @tagged type NewType = UnderlyingType" )
    }
  }
}

object TaggedImpl {
  def expand(underlyingType: Type.Name, newType: Type.Name, mods: Seq[Mod]) = {
    // Shapeless needs a phantom type to join with the underlying type to
    // create our tagged type. Ideally should never leak to external code.
    val tag = Type.Name(newType.value + "Tag")

    // The `fromX` helper will go in the companion object.
    val companionObject = Term.Name(newType.value)

    // We'll name the `fromX` method based on the underlying type.
    val fromMethod = Term.Name("from" + underlyingType.value)

    // The `untagged` helper goes in an implicit class, since the tagged type
    // is only a type alias, and can't have real methods. 
    val opsClass = Type.Name(newType.value + "Ops")

    q"""
      sealed trait $tag
      ..$mods type $newType = com.acjay.taggy.tag.@@[$underlyingType, $tag]
      ..$mods object $companionObject {
        def $fromMethod(untagged: $underlyingType): $newType = {
          val tagged = com.acjay.taggy.tag[$tag](untagged)
          tagged
        }
      }
      ..$mods implicit class $opsClass(val tagged: $newType) extends AnyVal { 
        def untagged = tagged.asInstanceOf[$underlyingType]
        def modify(f: $underlyingType => $underlyingType) = $companionObject.$fromMethod(f(untagged))
      }
    """
  }
}

object tag {
  def apply[U] = new Tagger[U]

  trait Tagged[U]
  type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

  class Tagger[U] {
    def apply[T](t : T) : T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
  }
}
```

The parsing of the macro syntax and code generation are separated for readability. You could inline `TaggedImpl.expand` into the `meta` block. Also note that the syntax here is now `@tagged type MyTaggedString = String`.

**Original answer**

I got it working as a proof of concept. But it takes the string name of the underlying type:

```
import scala.meta._

class tagged(_underlyingTypeName: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    // Can't figure out how to do this extraction as a quasiquote, so I 
    // figured out exactly the AST `this` produces to extract the string 
    // parameter.
    val Term.New(
      Template(
        List(),
        List(Term.Apply(Ctor.Ref.Name("tagged"), List(Lit.String(underlyingTypeName)))),
        Term.Param(List(), Name.Anonymous(), None, None),
        None
      )
    ) = this

    val q"..$mods type $tname[..$tparams]" = defn
    val underlyingType = Type.Name(underlyingTypeName)
    TaggedImpl.expand(tname, underlyingType)
  }
}

object TaggedImpl {
  def expand(taggedType: Type.Name, underlyingType: Type.Name) = {
    val tag = Type.Name(taggedType.value + "Tag")
    val companionObject = Term.Name(taggedType.value)
    val fromMethodName = Term.Name("from" + underlyingType.value)
    val opsClass = Type.Name(taggedType.value + "Ops")

    q"""
      sealed trait $tag
      type $taggedType = shapeless.tag.@@[$underlyingType, $tag]
      object $companionObject {
        def $fromMethodName(untagged: $underlyingType): $taggedType = {
          val tagged = shapeless.tag[$tag](untagged)
          tagged
        }
      }
      implicit class $opsClass(val tagged: $taggedType) extends AnyVal { 
        def untagged = tagged.asInstanceOf[$underlyingType] 
      }
    """
  }
}
```